# How to bind autocomplete to dynamically created text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am trying to bind my autocomplete to an input I dynamically created on a button click and I can't seem to get it to work. The field creates when one of the buttons with the addincidentwitness class is clicked  with no problem but the input text field does not do the lookup.  Below is the code.  First is the button.

```
<input type="button" class="addincidentwitness" value="Add MCH Person"/>
```

Here is the jquery code bound to the above button.  As you can see I am creating the input text field and below it is the function for the autocomplete for that input field.

```
$(function(){
$(".addincidentwitness").click(function(){
    if($(this).val()=="Add MCH Person"){
        $("#addwitnessdiv").empty();
        $("#addwitnessdiv").append(
            $('<label>').prop({for:"addmchwitness"}).text("MCH Person to Add") 
        ).append(
            $('<input>').prop({type:"text",name:"addmchwitness",id:"addmchwitness"})
        )
        $(function(){
            $("#addmchwitness").autocomplete({
                source:"../json/getanymchpersonjson.php",
                select:function(e,u){
                    if($("#"+u.item.Mchnum).length>0){
                        alert("You already have this employee as a witness.")
                    }else{
                        $("#witnessesdiv").append(
                            $('<div>').prop({id:u.item.Mchnum}).append(
                                $('<label>').text("MCH Person")      
                            ).append(
                                $('<input>').prop({type:"hidden",name:"witnessmchnums[]",value:u.item.Mchnum})    
                            ).append(
                                $('<input>').prop({type:"text",value:u.item.label,readonly:true})  
                            )
                        )
                    }
                    $("#addwitnessdiv").empty();
                },
                minLength:3
            })

        })
    }

})
})
```

There must be something wrong with how I am binding this to the field, but when I inspect the input field using chrome, it seems to attach the appropriate classes from jquery to the field. Below is the output of the field inspection.

```
<input type="text" name="addmchwitness" id="addmchwitness" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `$(function(){});` is jQuery short hand for `$(document).ready({});` - you only need one. Try removing the second instance from your example. There are also a number of javascript errors in your code :(

Comment: beside the obvious function(), what other errors are there?

Comment: Well, you're missing semi-colons to close the majority of your statements - at least based on the example you've posted.

Comment: I think the if-statement checking the button value is unnecessary, and as pointed out you can remove the extra `$(function(){});` and should add some semi-colons, but none of that causes it to not work. It appears to work fine in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sLL6vruz/).

Comment: I see where I missed several but and I have put them in.  I know you don't put them at the end of the element you have within the append statement.  Where else are they missing?

Comment: Oh the if statement is there because I will have another button of this same class to add other types of people so to do this I am using a class and then by checking the verbage of the button I figure out what group of people will be used in the autocomplete. I just have one button now to test the efficacy of the code.

Comment: You could consider using hide/show, rather than dynamically add the input each time the button is clicked like in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sLL6vruz/1/). Notice I added a call to `.focus()` on the input element.

Comment: I found the error in the php file.  There was another array in the json that was null.  I thought my partner checked this data.  I should have.  But having said that, I have learned several things and I think I am going to take the approach John S suggested.